# Wrap input with submit tag in one div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, erb

Let's say I have these fields generated by simple_form_for:

```
= f.input :amount, label: false, required: true
= f.submit "✓", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

I want to wrap them in one div and none of them should be nested inside any other div.

(it should look like this):

```
<form>
  <div class="inputFields">
     <input name="amount"> <!-- f.input -->
     <input name="commit"> <!-- f.submit -->
  </div>
</form>
```

now it looks like this:

```
<form>
  <div class="fieldcontainer">
     <input name="amount"> <!-- f.input -->
  </div>
  <input name="commit"> <!-- f.submit -->
</form>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: if you want to customize html elements in your form then why are you using simple_form? Use rails form_for helper and then customize it the way you want it to look like

Comment: @Mandeep simple_form adds quite a bit of functionality outside of just html wrappers. So it's perfectly valid to want that functionality and a different resulting html wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Simple Form documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#stripping-away-all-wrapper-divs), you can skip use of the wrapper html tags by using `input_field` instead of `input`. So, if this is just a one-off case then you could define your own wrapper div tag and turn off the auto-generated wrapper:

```
.inputFields
  = f.input_field :amount, label: false, required: true
  = f.submit "✓", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Or, if this is not a one-off case and is a common thing, you could create your own wrapper... See the [custom wrapper documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#the-wrappers-api) for help.